# How to get time from another zone with correct time in minutes and seconds C#

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

So, I have a problem with time zone

```
var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
var time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Eastern Standard Time").ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm");

var expectedResult = new List<string>(){"aaa", "bbb", $"{time}"};
var elements = element.Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

Time that I get from system is different from timezone. That time is about five minutes and it changes, probably depending on the moment my record is created. After that I have to verify, that values in lists are equal

For example: I get list of strings with actual result, which equal

```
var actualResult = new List<string>(){"aaa", "bbb", "{timeFromSystem}"};
```

Now I'm still getting different result with time and timeFromSystem.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: When handling time and time zones its best to use UTC for all handling and then convert to the time zone that you want, whether local or not e.g. `var currentTime = DateTime.UTCNow;`

Comment: I tried this way, but result the same time is different

Comment: What is `timeFromSystem`?  Where does it come from?  Is it a field on a record in a database?

Comment: timeFromSystem come after I created notes in another tab

Comment: Can you give us more information? Where are you obtaining the `timeFromSystem` from to compare against your calculated timezone value for `time`? What time zone is your `timeFromSystem` provider set to? If the source of your local time and your `timeFromSystem` are different e.g. different local PC, remote PC , are you certain that their clocks are synchronised?

Comment: I was given advice. Verify that time should be created, when test is ran and compare that time less then timeFromSystem. How to create time in same time when run test?

Comment: @ChrisBD: "When handling time and time zones its best to use UTC for all handling" - not always. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/